# Replace image in static folder Django 1.5

Tags: django, static

I uploaded an image, which saved in the database correctly and I'm able to view it using an  tag.

Now I wanted to replace the image. I went to the static folder where the image is stored and deleted the old one, then replace it with the new one ( with same name and extension).

The problem is when I refreshed my page, it still shows me previous image. What am I not doing correctly pls.

I have restarted my machine. Restarted my apache server. But it still shows old image

Comment: Do ctrl+f5 to bypass your browser cache

Comment: Hello, thank you for your contribution. This solution resolved the issue. Thank you